# Different _source filtering for each query in msearch

Tags: search, elasticsearch

Greetings overflowers,

I am using ElasticSearch 2.0 API. I have few queries that are executed together using msearch. I would like to specify different _source filtering options for each query (just like _type), however these options seem to be ignored (i.e. nothing is filtered).

Any idea?

Sample queries:

```
elasticsearch.msearch({
    index: 'some_index',
    body: [
        {
            _type: 'type_a',
            _source_exclude: ['field_a', 'field_b'].join()
        },
        {query: {constant_score: {filter: {term: {field_c: valueA}}}}},
        {
            _type: 'type_b',
            _source_exclude: ['field_d', 'field_e'].join()
        },
        {query: {constant_score: {filter: {term: {field_f: valueB}}}}}
    ]
}, function msearch(err, results) { /* logic... */ });
```

Comment: Can you show the request you're sending?

Comment: Please, see sample queries above. The problem is that _source_exclude does not work

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [source filtering](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.0/search-request-source-filtering.html) docs, you should do it like this instead:

```
elasticsearch.msearch({
    index: 'some_index',
    body: [
        {
            _type: 'type_a',
            _sourceExclude: ['field_a', 'field_b']
        },
        {query: {constant_score: {filter: {term: {field_c: valueA}}}}},
        {
            _type: 'type_b',
            _sourceExclude: ['field_d', 'field_e']
        },
        {query: {constant_score: {filter: {term: {field_f: valueB}}}}}
    ]
}, function msearch(err, results) { /* logic... */ });
```

Comment: Tried your suggestion with no luck. Have you tried it?

Comment: My bad, I've fixed the query, sorry about that, please try again.